Change JSON code from localStorage to server-side
I am new to JSON and need some help changing the code to utilize a server-side .json file rather than localStorage.
This is for a simple inventory database I require and should not use SQL. Javascript or jQuery would be best. I have searched the web without any helpful examples.
JSON seems easy enough, but I'm stumped here. I do have a hosted server that would allow me to run this.
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Inventory System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Inventory System</h1>
        <form id="inventoryForm">
            <input type="text" id="itemOwner" placeholder="Technicians Name" required>
            <input type="text" id="itemName" placeholder="Item Name" required>
            <input type="number" id="itemQuantity" placeholder="Quantity" required>
            <input type="number" id="itemPrice" placeholder="Price" required>
            <button type="submit">Add Item</button>
        </form>
        <table id="inventoryTable">
            <tr>
                <th>Owner</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

JAVASCRIPT
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const form = document.getElementById("inventoryForm");
    const table = document.getElementById("inventoryTable");
    const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("inventoryItems")) || [];

    // Function to update and display the inventory table
    function updateInventoryTable() {
        table.innerHTML = `
            <tr>
                <th>Owner</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        `;

        items.forEach((item, index) => {
            const row = document.createElement("tr");
            row.innerHTML = `
                <td>${item.owner}</td>
                <td>${item.name}</td>
                <td>${item.quantity}</td>
                <td>${item.price}</td>
                <td>
                    <button onclick="editItem(${index})">Edit</button>
                    <button onclick="deleteItem(${index})">Delete</button>
                </td>
            `;
            table.appendChild(row);
        });
    }

    // Function to add a new item to the inventory
    function addItem(owner, name, quantity, price) {
        items.push({owner, name, quantity, price });
        localStorage.setItem("inventoryItems", JSON.stringify(items));
        updateInventoryTable();
    }

    // Function to delete an item from the inventory
    function deleteItem(index) {
        items.splice(index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem("inventoryItems", JSON.stringify(items));
        updateInventoryTable();
    }

    // Function to handle form submission and add new items
    form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const itemOwner = document.getElementById("itemOwner").value;
        const itemName = document.getElementById("itemName").value;
        const itemQuantity = document.getElementById("itemQuantity").value;
         const itemPrice = document.getElementById("itemPrice").value;
        addItem(itemOwner, itemName, itemQuantity, itemPrice);
        form.reset();
    });

    // Function to edit an existing item in the inventory
    window.editItem = (index) => {
        const newOwner = prompt("Enter the new owners name:");
        const newName = prompt("Enter the new item name:");
        const newQuantity = prompt("Enter the new quantity:");
        const newPrice = prompt("Enter the new price:");
        if (newOwner && newName && newQuantity && newPrice) {
            items[index].owner = newOwner;
            items[index].name = newName;
            items[index].quantity = newQuantity;
            items[index].price = newPrice;
            localStorage.setItem("inventoryItems", JSON.stringify(items));
            updateInventoryTable();
        }
    };

    // Function to delete an item from the inventory
    window.deleteItem = (index) => {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")) {
            deleteItem(index);
        }
    };

    // Initialize the inventory table
    updateInventoryTable();
});


You should show an example of your JSON to get help.

It looks like this problem is more about how to store and retrieve data, rather than JSON in specific


Convert your domContentLoaded function to a named function that takes items as a parameter.  Delete the line that loads items from localStorage.

In your now empty domContentLoaded function, start a fetch and call the new named function in a .then.  Note that how exactly to handle the response depends on what exactly the json looks like.  I assume it's an array.




function processInventoryItems(items) {
    const form = document.getElementById("inventoryForm");
    const table = document.getElementById("inventoryTable");

    // Function to update and display the inventory table
    function updateInventoryTable() {
        table.innerHTML = `
            <tr>
                <th>Owner</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        `;

        items.forEach((item, index) => {
            const row = document.createElement("tr");
            row.innerHTML = `
                <td>${item.owner}</td>
                <td>${item.name}</td>
                <td>${item.quantity}</td>
                <td>${item.price}</td>
                <td>
                    <button onclick="editItem(${index})">Edit</button>
                    <button onclick="deleteItem(${index})">Delete</button>
                </td>
            `;
            table.appendChild(row);
        });
    }

    // Function to add a new item to the inventory
    function addItem(owner, name, quantity, price) {
        items.push({owner, name, quantity, price });
        localStorage.setItem("inventoryItems", JSON.stringify(items));
        updateInventoryTable();
    }

    // Function to delete an item from the inventory
    function deleteItem(index) {
        items.splice(index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem("inventoryItems", JSON.stringify(items));
        updateInventoryTable();
    }

    // Function to handle form submission and add new items
    form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const itemOwner = document.getElementById("itemOwner").value;
        const itemName = document.getElementById("itemName").value;
        const itemQuantity = document.getElementById("itemQuantity").value;
         const itemPrice = document.getElementById("itemPrice").value;
        addItem(itemOwner, itemName, itemQuantity, itemPrice);
        form.reset();
    });

    // Function to edit an existing item in the inventory
    window.editItem = (index) => {
        const newOwner = prompt("Enter the new owners name:");
        const newName = prompt("Enter the new item name:");
        const newQuantity = prompt("Enter the new quantity:");
        const newPrice = prompt("Enter the new price:");
        if (newOwner && newName && newQuantity && newPrice) {
            items[index].owner = newOwner;
            items[index].name = newName;
            items[index].quantity = newQuantity;
            items[index].price = newPrice;
            localStorage.setItem("inventoryItems", JSON.stringify(items));
            updateInventoryTable();
        }
    };

    // Function to delete an item from the inventory
    window.deleteItem = (index) => {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")) {
            deleteItem(index);
        }
    };

    // Initialize the inventory table
    updateInventoryTable();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  // you could also define processInventoryItems here if preferred

  fetch(inventoryItemsJsonUrl).then(response => {
    const items = response.json();
    processInventoryItems(items);
  });
});




That looks good, however it’s throwing me an error. I assume that I would need to set the url path for the variable inventoryItemsJsonUrl ?

Yes please replace it with the actual url

That's not working unfortunately. I added the path of the file (which should be the same as the html and js file) but it's not working. Do I need the name of the .json file as well? What would the file name be? Sorry for being a noob - but your help would be greatly appreciated.

You would need to have already created a json file with the appropriate data and hosted it on your server for this to work.  This example is only showing you how to handle loading that json.

Thanks. And what do I name the file and reference it in the js code? Can you show me the js code  using a file named "inventory.json" located at the root of the js, please?

It’s really as simple as fetch("inventory.json").then( // same as above )
